# how to show multidimentional array result using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uniq_id] => 00fdc23c151ad0044d60
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uniq_id] => 590dde424e
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uniq_id] => 6f0eb3bb34
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uniq_id] => eeb6c63929
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [uniq_id] => a72034387e
                )
                     }
}
```

But I want only   multiple `uniq_id`  one by one in `foreach` loop

like

```
00fdc23c151ad0044d60

590dde424e

6f0eb3bb34

eeb6c63929

a72034387e
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please post your attempts too.

Answer (score 3):

Its a `stdClass Object array`, so try this:

```
foreach($yourArray['result'] as $data)
{
    echo $date->uniq_id.'<br>';
}
```

**Note:** `stdClass` Object `properties` can be accessed using `->`

Comment: sorry its not working                                                                                                                     Notice: Undefined variable: date in D:\WampServer\wamp\www\file_get_content\index.php on line 12

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\WampServer\wamp\www\file_get_content\index.php on line 12